# Configure build.xml to run JUnit tests in separate /test directory

Tags: java, xml, junit, travis-ci, build.xml

I'm trying to create a build.xml file to use with Travis CI.

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Practice" basedir="." default="init">
   <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
   <property name="bin.dir" location="bin" />
   <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />
   <path id="classpath">
      <pathelement location="${bin.dir}" />
      <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
      <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.11.jar" />
   </path>
   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
   </target>
   <target name="init" depends="clean">
      <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
      <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${bin.dir}">
         <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch" />
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
         </fileset>
      </copy>
   </target>
   <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile">
      <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
   </target>
   <target name="test" depends="compile">
      <mkdir dir="${report.dir}" />
      <junit printsummary="yes">
         <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath" />
         </classpath>
         <formatter type="xml" />
         <test name="folder1.MyClass1Test" todir="${report.dir}" haltonfailure="yes" />
      </junit>
   </target>
</project>
```

If I place my JUnit test files in the same directory as the class files, like in the file structure shown below, the above build.xml works, and the JUnit test runs properly:

```
- src
  - folder1
    - MyClass1.java
    - MyClass1Test.java
```

I, however, have my test files in a separate /test directory and the structure looks something like the following:

```
- src
  - folder1
    - MyClass1.java
- test
  - folder1
    - MyClass1Test.java
```

I can't seem to figure out what I need to change to get the test to run from the /test folder. I tried changing the `src.dir` location in different spots to point to `test` instead of `src`, but the I then get errors that different packages don't exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Ant instead of a modern build tool?

Comment: @chrylis I just started exploring the world of CI, and this is just the first method I came across. I'd be happy to hear about alternative tools that I can check out, but it would still be nice if I can get this method working.

Comment: @chrylis When you say "modern build tool", are you referring to Gradle or Maven?

Comment: Mostly. Either one handles all of this stuff as a matter of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should/must define another target that compiles your test sources:

```
<target name="compileTest" depends="compile" description="compileTest">
  <javac srcdir="${test-src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
</target>
```

Your test target then becomes

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
  ...
</target>
```

Make sure to add the additional property `test-src.dir`.